# How early should I arrive for same-day tickets for the Washington Monument?

Tags: tickets, planning, tips-and-tricks, sightseeing, washington-dc

Quoting https://www.recreation.gov/ticket/facility/234635,

> Same-day, free tickets will also be available on a first-come, first-served basis daily, starting at 8:30 a.m.

My question is...  at what time should I get to the Washington Monument to get a same-day ticket on, say, Saturday, October 26? If I get there at 8:30am will there be such a long line that I will be unlikely to get the tickets even if I wait in line?

What if I got there at 8:00am and just waited until they opened? I could get there at 7:30am as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I were you I'd be prepared for an early morning. Other attractions I have visited offering free passes on a first come first served basis usually tend to attract massive queues hours before the opening of the ticket office. [This also send to be true for the Washington Monument](https://freetoursbyfoot.com/tickets-to-tour-the-washington-monument/):

> ### NOTE FOR SAME DAY TICKETS TO THE WASHINGTON MONUMENT:
>
> If you plan on getting same-day tickets to the Washington Monument during Spring/Summer months, expect an early morning.
>
> - Ticket handouts begin at 8:30 am, but the line starts to form as early as 7 am
> - Tickets are given out on a first come, first served basis, so morning times tend to go fast.
> - Each person can obtain up to 6 tickets.
> - Tickets can be fully distributed by 9:30 am.
>
> ### Visitor’s Tip:
>
> If you don’t get same day tickets, you may still be in luck.
>
> School groups visiting between March-June often order too many tickets in advance. Since they cannot use them all, many groups will hand out tickets to guests waiting around the base of the memorial.
>
> There is no way to time this so fate has to be on your side, but if its a nice day and you see a lot of prepubescent middle-schoolers in matching t-shirts, it may be worth hanging out to see!

Comment: I got in line at 7:30am and, by my count, there were 70 people ahead of me at that time. I managed to get a ticket without issue but I was just getting one ticket. Some of the time slots were already gone by the time I reached the front. Overall, the line moved pretty fast!